# How to use Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC C# without the following errors?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create user profile by including name,adress,birthday and telephone number of users. But i have register form with email,confirm password and password fields only. Can I edit RegisterViewModel.cs file in Models under Account.cs and add my rest of values like name,address kind of things? When i'm going to create a controller (MVC 5 Controller with views, using entity framework) using that editted model it is giving me an error as follows:

Error :

[image]

Comment: "no keys defined". Google that and you will see a couple ways to do it.

Comment: No i have defined a key also.

Comment: public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all relevant code. See [ask] and [mcve],